# How to set row and column index as lat/lon in a dataframe in python?and then make a xarray dataset with lat,lon and values as variables

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe.I want to make the row column index with latitude,longitude.

```
longitude=np.arange(-180,180,0.05)
latitude=np.arange(-90,90,0.05)
```

I want to set this lat,lon as row and column index of the dataframe.[Here is the picture of the dataframe.Though here only "nan" is visible but some points have proper value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J97FU.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J97FU.png)

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: A dataframe of which library (pandas, polars, spark,...)? Add an appropriate tag.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your intention is not fully clear. However maybe what you want is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns= longitude, index = latitude)
```

to create the DF:

```
       -180.00 -179.95 -179.90 -179.85  ...  179.80  179.85  179.90  179.95
-90.00     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
-89.95     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
-89.90     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
-89.85     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
-89.80     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
...        ...     ...     ...     ...  ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
 89.75     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
 89.80     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
 89.85     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
 89.90     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
 89.95     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN

[3600 rows x 7200 columns]
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to make xarray dataset from this dataframe with lat lon and the values as variables?

Comment: Then please hit the green tick mark on the left and update your question to address the two comments up there.

Comment: I have hit the green mark and have updated my question.If possible please help me to solve my question

Comment: Does this [Link to Use](https://www.slingacademy.com/article/pandas-how-to-convert-a-dataframe-to-an-xarray-4-examples/) answer your question about converting to xarray? Else please explain what you are trying to do / expecting.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Your provided ranges
longitude = np.arange(-180, 180, 0.05)
latitude = np.arange(-90, 90, 0.05)

# Example: Creating an empty dataframe with latitude and longitude as multi-index
# This assumes you want every possible combination of latitude and longitude as an index
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([latitude, longitude], names=["Latitude", "Longitude"])
df = pd.DataFrame(index=index)

# Now, df is ready to be populated with your data.
# Each row corresponds to a unique combination of latitude and longitude.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just reassign the index (of the rows) and (the names of) the columns:

```py
df.columns = longitude
df.index = latitude
```

Result:

```py
       -180.00 -179.95 -179.90 -179.85  ...  179.80  179.85  179.90  179.95
-90.00     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
-89.95     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
-89.90     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
-89.85     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
-89.80     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
       ...     ...     ...     ...  ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
 89.75     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
 89.80     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
 89.85     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
 89.90     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
 89.95     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```